# Twitter Node in Node-RED - no tweets in debug tab

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud, node-red

I am new with bluemix and node red and wanted to start with a simple example.
I have set up a simple flow. Twitter In node and debug node connected together. However although I have provided twitter credentials and also have defined the msg.payload within the debug node, I do not see any tweets in the debug tab.
(I have deployed the nodes and my app is up and running).

What might be the reason for this?

Edit:
I also see the behavior that following message occurs sometimes:
Error: Lost connection to server

Comment: Are there any messages in the log? cf logs [app name] will tail the log. Also what search options did you give the Twitter node?

Comment: This is the output of the log:

http://pastebin.com/1fn6dBqP

My search options are: all public tweets for the tag A1Telekom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put the same details into a local copy of Node-RED everything looks all right.

What I think you are seeing here is the fact that the Twitter-in node uses the streaming API not the search API. This means you will only see new Tweets. A quick look at the A1Telekom account shows that it's only tweeted once since the 23rd July. Also there doesn't look to be a lot traffic from others mentioning them.

Also you will also only see tweets in the debug tab if you are connected to the Node-RED console so if new tweets arrive while your not connected then they will be processed by Node-RED but not displayed.